# Mac/Java-7: Why does TextField not get the expected KEY_PRESSED events when Alt is down?

Tags: java, macos, java-7

When executing a keyboard event that includes an 'Alt,' Mac/Java-7 does not propagate a KEY_PRESSED against a non-modifier key in the key sequence against TextFields.

This behavior is not reproducible against other modifier keys like Cmd or Ctrl.

For example, when compiling and running the below code and executing a 'Alt + o' keystroke in the TextField, all platforms, except Mac/Java 7, output the following key event sequence (note that there is a KEY_PRESSED for both the 'alt' and the 'o'):

java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=18,keyText=?,keyChar=Undefined keyChar,modifiers=?

java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=79,keyText=O,keyChar='ø',modifiers=?

java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar='ø',modifiers=?

java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=79,keyText=O,keyChar='ø',modifiers=?...

java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=18,keyText=?,keyChar=Undefined...

However, on Mac/Java-7 (tested up to patch 10), you get the above without the KEY_PRESSED representing the 'o' (KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=79,keyText=O,keyChar='ø'). The KEY_TYPED event might not be the most helpful substitute because it doesn't have modifiers or a keyCode, at least without tracking some state.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ScratchKeyEvent {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JTextField field = new JTextField(10);

    field.addKeyListener(createListener());

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(field);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private static KeyListener createListener() {
    return new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("keyTyped " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("keyPressed " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("keyReleased " + e);
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead?

Comment: keybindings in this case wouldn't help without a lot of work. I'm doing some real time translation of keystrokes.

Comment: Them I'd suggest using a DocumentListener instead, but I don't have a context for what you are trying to do